# WebBrowser Control — Get Document Elements After AJAX Call — Null Exception

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, browser, windows

I'm writing an application that uses the WebBrowser control to view web content that can change with `AJAX` that adds new content/elements.
I can't seem to get at the new elements any way I've tried...
`webBrowser1.DocumentText` doesn't have the up-to-date page(after AJAX).
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Eelement that comes afetr AJAX and i want it") always returns Null.

Is there some way to get this new data using this control?
let's to see my codes :

```
    private void btnStartRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
           webBrowser1.Navigate("www.sample.com");
    }

    private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("register").InvokeMember("click");
            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("element that comes afetr AJAX Call and i want it").InvokeMember("click"); -> I have error in this line...
    }
```

`i am using visual studio 2010 - windows application - .net 4 - c#`

thanks in advance

Comment: where did u insert that(answer) code snippet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while ((wb.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)) {
    Application.DoEvents();
}
```

;)

Comment: where do you write it?